# How much time does qualifying for a fishing license in Germany take?

Tags: fishing, germany

My brother asked me lately if I wanted to join a fishing license class with him later this year. I would absolutely like that but I'm afraid that I can't handle the additional time consumption.

How much time do I have to calculate with?

---

**Edit, since flagged:**

I ask for the time a license consumes in Baden-Württemberg. I mean the actual time of the whole course. So, how many hours of fishing training (is there such a thing?), how many hours of theoretical classes and how many hours of exams. This sum is the time a course consumes.

For example: a driving license in Germany needs at least (made up numbers) 7 hours of night-driving, 5 hours of rural driving, 5 hours in the city, 12 theoretical classes with an hour each and finally the exams consuming 2 hours. That makes a consumption of 31 hours.

Comment: Maybe change "making" a fishing license to either "qualifying for" or "getting"? "Making" made me think you were asking how long to forge a license, which is clearly wrong.

Comment: You have to have lessons for a fishing license?! Wow, in the UK you just pay a fee and get given one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the state, and the kind of course.

In some states you don't need a license any more, or could even purchase a tourist-license valid for few weeks.

The course can take just a few days, with a final test at the end, but sometimes it is difficult to find a course in a certain time frame. It can happen that you will have to wait a month, or even more, to be able to take a course at all.

If your brother actually has a course with a fitting time frame, he should be able to tell you how long the course is, ask him.

Otherwise you should check out which laws apply the the state, when courses are offered, and how long they take.

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules or laws, as far as I know, on how much needs to be done for the fishing license. It always depends on the School you are doing it in. I did mine on a weekend in Mecklenburg Vorpommern.

It was 2,5h of theoretical lessons and 2 evenings of fishing, but mostly without a instructor, since I was fishing in denmark a bunch of times before.

So if you can fish and know most of the basics I wouldn't say it's very complicated. Just find a nice place with a good offer and friendly instructors and it will be a lot of fun!